Request forwarding issue with Spring Boot application running on Tomcat with 8080 port with load balancer running on 443 port
I have Spring Boot application running on 8080 port (default port) with ReactJS files for UI part.
DevOps created application load balancer in GCP on port 443.
When URL is submitted from browser (https://hostname/APPNAME/login) with credentials Spring Security config class is invoked, after authentication validation, URL is forwarded to
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")

Issue: forward URL is having port 443 appended and server never finds URL at 443 port and browser displays page not found error.
Can you provide a suggestion, how it should be handled?

Show your response with headers.
